# MS Access "After Update" events: raise error

Tags: database, ms-access, triggers, sql-update, ms-access-2016

Raising error using `After Update` is not possible, while using `Before Update` is possible.
[image: 'After Update' is not fired at all, while 'Before Update' is fired]

To test it, I create a `RaiseError` event on `Before Change`:

[image: before change event definition]

Whenever I change a record, an error box is shown:

[image]

But when we set `RaiseError` on `After Update` nothing is shown after record changes.

[image: after update definition]

I use *Microsoft® Access® 2016*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after two days exploration, I find the problem. The errors defined on `After Change` is not shown as an error message box. They are logged on `Application Log`.

[image]